# Find proper notch filter to remove noise from image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering, noise

I want to eliminate periodic noise from an image using  notch filter. i do the following steps :

```
I = imread('...img....');
ft = fftshift(fft2(I));
[m,n] = size(ft);
filt = ones(m,n);
%filt(......) = 0; % my problem is here 
ft = ft .* filt;
ifft_ = ifft2(ifftshift( ft));
```

[so i don't know what exactly to set to zero to get the proper result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNBzE.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

The main idea behind the notch filter is to zero out a small amount of frequencies in the FFT image, which causes noises.

In order to find them, you can look at the FFT magnitude:

```
F = abs(ft2); 
F = log(F+1); 
imshow(F,[])
```

It is possible to see that the peaks in the frequency image, are located at the following points:

```
pnts2del ={[88,155],[101,92],[138,71],[125,134]};
```

[image]

If you zero out each of these points surroundings you will get a cleaner image:

```
G = 60;
for ii=1:length(pnts2del)
    pnt = pnts2del{ii};
    filt(pnt(1),pnt(2)-G:pnt(2)+G) = 0;
    filt(pnt(1)-G:pnt(1)+G,pnt(2)) = 0;
    filt(pnt(1)-1:pnt(1)+1,pnt(2)-1:pnt(2)+1) = 0;
end
```

result (before and after, and updated FFT):

[image]
[image]

Comment: tnx for your answer . how do you determine G?

Comment: tnx for your answer . how do you determine G?

Comment: can you give me the whole code plz? the ft matrix and filt matrix are not in same size. so, i can not calculate ft = ft .* filt. tnx again

Comment: @Ibezito +1 for gr8 example. In your program `pnts2del ={[88,155],[101,92],[138,71],[125,134]};` did you manually find these points or did you write  a code to find it?

Comment: thanks @JeruLuke, it was manually in this case. It is possible however to write a code who searches for these peaks in the Fourier image

Comment: @Ibezito ok, so we have to search for 'peaks' in Fourier domain. I will try it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this image.

[image: Notch locations]

This is the FFT of an image with similar noise problems to yours. Those red circles are pointing out the 'spikes' in the frequency domain associated with that type of noise. Take a look at your image and see if you can find those.

Those spikes are what you're going to want to eliminate. In other words, your filter should have a value of zero at those locations, and a value of one at all other locations. Then, when you multiply in the following line, you will be eliminating that information, and drastically reducing the noise associated with it.